# How to recover my github email can't remember it?

Tags: github

I need help to recover my GitHub account with the username: raoudhatrimech2 the problem is that I forget the email that use to register on GitHub.

Please is there a method to recover it via my username?

If someone can help me, I gonna happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call or write the GitHub support to solve your issue.